# Include excerpts from a document in another document

Tags: content-replication

I have a manuscript and its revision report. I need to put some sentences of this manuscript to the revision report as excerpts. Instead of defining excerpts as macros or putting the excerpts in another file and then including them, is there a better solution to use the text of the manuscript in the revision report?

I expect a solution like:

Contents of `manuscript.tex`:

```
...
Pragraph is starting.
\begin{externalize}[excerpt1]
Part that must be both in the manuscript and the revision report.
\end{externalize}
Paragraph ends.
...
```

Contents of `revisionReport.tex`:

```
...
Here we include the following excerpt from the revised manuscript:

\externalizedtext{excerpt1}
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`filecontents`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/filecontents) to create excerpt files on the fly:

Contents of `manuscript.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}
... 

Pragraph is starting.

\begin{filecontents}{excerpt1.tex}
Part that must be both in the manuscript and the revision report.
\end{filecontents}
\input{excerpt1.tex}

Paragraph ends.

...
\end{document}
```

Contents of `revisionReport.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
...

Here we include the following excerpt from the revised manuscript:

\input{excerpt1.tex}

...

\end{document}
```

This should do the trick, although I am not completely sure I understood your question correctly.

Comment: Dear @Martin, your answer would be grate if `\begin{filecontents}...\end{filecontents}` were allowed to be used in the body of the document. I got this error for your code: `! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.`

Comment: @kadir Natively that is true. The `\usepackage{filecontents}` should overcome these restrictions. You might have forgotten to put it in your preamble, or do not have the package installed. Have you tried to compile the MWEs?